# Umbraco action with parmeter error: "Page not found No umbraco document matches the url '/About/Topic?topic=aloha'."

Tags: umbraco

I have this problem. I created the "Topic" action with the parameter "topic" but when I go to "About / Topic? topic = aloha" I can not find this action and I get an error: "Page not found
No umbraco document matches the url '/ About / Topic? Topic = aloha'. "

Controller:

```
public class AboutController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    // GET: About
    public ActionResult About(RenderModel model)
    {
        return View("About", model);
    }

    public ActionResult Topic( string topic)
    {
        return View("About");
    }
}
```

Routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default1",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{topic}",
        defaults: new { controller = "About", action = "Topic", topic = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Umbraco Mvc controller you'll have to create your routes in the Umbraco pipeline and not in the regular MVC routing.

From the docs:

*You can specify your own custom MVC routes to work within the Umbraco pipeline. This requires you to use an implementation of Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler with your custom route.*

For Umbraco V7 more info [here](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Routing/custom-routes-v7#custom-routes-within-the-umbraco-pipeline)

For Umbraco V8 more info [here](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Routing/custom-routes#custom-routes-within-the-umbraco-pipeline)